# Keep working with bash while a program is running

Tags: bash

I know, this is a very stupid question and the answer is out there in Googleland. But I just can't find it.

I want to start a process/program (e.g. firefox) in bash and keep working with the terminal. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Markus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send it to the background, by putting an `&` after the command, so e.g.:

```
firefox &
```

The bash will print out a job number for it e.g:

```
[1] 4510
```

means that the job number is `1`. Then you can bring it back to the foreground when you want by `fg` and its job number, e.g.:

```
fg 1
```

Comment: I was typing the same answer, you beat me to it ;). I would like to add that it will show the PID number. you can stop the process by running `kill <PID>`